# Javascript output an array with two values where both values are separated with their own variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

To elaborate my question, I would like to separate the two values in my array into their own variables, then output them using for each. So it could go for something like:

for each -> 
name + '-' value

Result:

```
Apple - 1
Banana - 2
Orange - 3
```

I am trying to do the output above using the code below

```
var groceries =[
{"Apple": 1},
{"Banana": 2},
{"Orange": 3}
];

var name = groceries.map(c => object.values(c)[0]);
var value = groceries.map(d => Object.values(d)[0]);

name.forEach(function(g_name) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = g_name;
});

value.forEach(function(g_value) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = g_value;
});
```

I have the output of the int working, showing 1, 2, 3 but its the string part that I have been troubling with.

Since the array goes like [object Object], I thought using a lowercase in object.values will help but I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: object is not defined on line`

Also I would like to know what kind of "document" echo could I do to combine the for each of both variables.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating two separate arrays, consider creating just one array, of the object's entries, then insert the key and the value, separated by a `-`:

```js
var groceries =[
  {"Apple": 1},
  {"Banana": 2},
  {"Orange": 3}
];

for (const [[key, value]] of groceries.map(Object.entries)) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = `${key} - ${value}`;
}
```

Problems with your current code:

- Don't use `name` as a top-level variable, because it'll always be coerced to a string (also, good to use precise variable names - it helps prevent bugs!)
- `object.values` won't work - you need `Object.values`
- Use `Object.keys` to get the keys - using `Object.values` twice will just give you the values twice
- If you go with the two-array route, when iterating over one of the arrays, look up the same index you're iterating over in the other array in order to have access to both the key and its corresponding at once, so you can insert it into the HTML

Fixing your original code:

```js
const groceries = [{
    "Apple": 1
  },
  {
    "Banana": 2
  },
  {
    "Orange": 3
  }
];

const groceryNames = groceries.map(c => Object.keys(c)[0]);
const groceryValues = groceries.map(d => Object.values(d)[0]);

groceryNames.forEach(function(g_name, i) {
  const value = groceryValues[i];
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = `${g_name} - ${value}`;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Befor the answer

there is a typo in `var name = groceries.map(c => object.values(c)[0]);` should be `Object.values`

`name` is a globally reserved variable, don't use it. use `names` instead

Solution:

loop through `groceries`,

get the first key of the object item like this `key = Object.keys(obj)[0]`

create a div with desired output using key and value like this: `key + ' - ' + obj[key]`

Working example

```js
var groceries =[
{"Apple": 1},
{"Banana": 2},
{"Orange": 3}
];

// may be it would be better to use one loop in this case
groceries.forEach((obj) => {
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0] // getting a single first key of object
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = 
   key + ' - ' + obj[key];
})
```